# Use method of direct proof to prove the statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

> If $n$ is a natural number such that $ n \geq 2$, then the numbers $n! + 2, n! + 3, n! + 4... n! + n$ are all composite.
>   (Thus, for any n greater than or equal to 2, one can find n consecutive composite numbers)

I started with just plugging in numbers to see if they were composite and they were. But I don't know how to prove it for all natural numbers.

Comment: You could start by showing that for $n \geq 2$ the numbers $2, 3, 4, \cdots, n$ all divide $n !$

Answer (score 2):

For $ 2 \leq i \leq n, \ \ \ n! + i = n(n-1)(n-2) \ldots i \ldots (3)(2)(1) + i $

$ = i( \ (n)(n-1)\ldots (i+1)(1)(i-1)\ldots (3)(2)(1) + 1 \ )$

which is clearly composite

Answer (score 2):

The statement you have to prove is that if $ 2 \leq k \leq n$ then $n! + k$ is composite.

Isn't $k$ a factor of $n!$?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that if $k \le n $ then $k $ divides $n! $.  So $k $ divides $n! +k $.  So $n! +k $ is composite if $k >1$.

let $\overline n_k=n!/k = 1*2*.... (k-1)*(k+l)*...*n $.  Then $n!+k =k (\overline n_k +1)$.

Comment: Oops, I thought I was making a comment.  Oh, well.

Answer (score 1):

$n ! + k = k\cdot(n\cdot(n - 1)\cdot...\cdot (k + 1)\cdot(k - 1)\cdot... \cdot 2\cdot 1 + 1), 2\leq k \leq n.$